# How to create javadoc with UMLGraph from Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, javadoc

I'm using UMLGraph to create class diagram for each class in my project in Intellij IDEA. The code of my `/app/build.gradle` is:

```
allprojects {
    configurations {
        umljavadoc
    }

    dependencies {
        umljavadoc 'org.umlgraph:umlgraph:5.6'
    }

    //
    // While javadoc is not typically dependent on compilation, the compile steps
    // sometimes generate some sources that we wish to have in the Javadoc.
    //
    task javadoc(overwrite: true, dependsOn: build) {
        setDescription('Generates Javadoc API documentation with UMLGraph diagrams')
        setGroup(JavaBasePlugin.DOCUMENTATION_GROUP)

        doLast {
            def javaFilePath = file('src/main/java')
            if (javaFilePath.exists())
            {
                ant.javadoc(classpath: "{path_to android jar}",
                        sourcepath: file('src/main/java'),
                        packagenames: '*',
                        destdir: "{path_to_doc_dir}",
                        private: 'true',
                        docletpath: configurations.umljavadoc.asPath,
                        charset: 'UTF-8',
                        encoding: 'UTF-8',
                        docencoding: 'UTF-8') {
                    doclet(name: 'org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc')
                            {
                                param(name: '-inferrel')
                                param(name: '-inferdep')
                                param(name: '-qualify')
                                param(name: '-postfixpackage')
                                param(name: '-hide', value: 'java.*')
                                param(name: '-collpackages', value: 'java.util.*')
                                param(name: '-nodefontsize', value: '9')
                                param(name: '-nodefontpackagesize', value: '7')
                                param(name: '-link', value: 'http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/doclet/spec')
                                param(name: '-link', value: 'http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/docs/api')
                            }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print("!!! Cannot find source path !!!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If i start `gradlew javadoc` from console everything is fine, it creates and inserts all the diagrams. But if i try to generate documentation with IDE (`Tools - Generate Javadoc...`), the diagrams are not be created.

If i try to run task `javadoc` from `Gradle view`, it inserts text placeholders instead of real diagrams.

**The question is: how to generate javadoc with UMLGraph diagrams with dialog `Tools - Generate Javadoc...`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under "Other command line arguments" in the Generate JavaDoc dialog, you can add the -docletpath and -doclet parameter pointing to your doclet class, followed by the arguments that are specific to your doclet.